# How can I get the request hostname in nuxt.config.js/i18n?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

I am trying to dynamically set the `baseUrl` property of nuxt/i18n depending on the request headers in nuxt.config.js

nuxt.config.js

```js
i18n: {
    baseUrl: ({ req }) => {
      return "https://" + req.headers.host;
    }
},
```

This doesn't work. Is there any way to access the request headers?

Nuxt: v2.15.7

i18n/nuxt: v7.0.1

Comment: What do you mean by request hostname? Are you looking for the client side version aka `location.origin`? Don't you want to pass an ENV variable for this one?

Comment: Sorry, if I was unclear, I am looking for the server-side version, aka context.req.headers.hostname. I am aware I can specify it in .env file and use in config, but I want to serve several domains and have to get the domain name from the request.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, found another solution. Nuxt.config.js is processed both on server side and client side with different contexts. At the server side I obtain the request `host` header and pass it to the client side through `nuxtState`.
More info here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/internals-glossary/context#beforenuxtrender

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
i18n: {
    baseUrl: (context) => {
      // get the hostname from http request headers on the server side and save it to nuxtState
      if (process.server) {
        const { req, beforeNuxtRender } = context;
        beforeNuxtRender(({ nuxtState }) => {
          nuxtState.host = req.headers.host;
        });
      }
      return (
        "https://" +
        (process.server ? context.req.headers.host : context.nuxtState.host)
      );
    },
...
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`serverMiddleware`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-servermiddleware) in your `nuxt.config.js` file

```js
serverMiddleware: ['~/server-middleware/logger']
```

`~/server-middleware/logger.js`

```js
export default function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('current host', req.headers.host)
  next()
}
```

And maybe set a cookie or alike, then use it in your `nuxt.config.js` for the other modules.

---

Otherwise, it is also used in the Nuxt context: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/context-helpers
So, either `asyncData`, `plugins`, `middleware` or `nuxtServerInit`.

Comment: Ok, thank you, and how would you pass the hostname variable from the middleware to nuxt.config.js then?

Comment: `And maybe set a cookie or alike, then use it in your nuxt.config.js for the other modules.` @user2779340